# Can the program store the password even if I did not store them?

Tags: c#, winforms, security

I'm trying to write a program that will get the current username and domain name, then ask the user to enter his/her own password for security purpose, if it verify then it will lead the user to the main program.

My question is after the user exit the program will the username, domain name, or password store in the cache. Or it will not store any of that in the computer.

If it will store it in the cache. How do I make sure that none of that will store it anywhere in the program after the user exit the program.

**Edit**

I'm using `using System.Security.Principal;` to get the username and domain name.

As for the password I use the window form to ask the user to enter the password.

Currently I'm just program in window form and not web programming.

Thank you

Comment: Are you validating with LDAP?

Comment: You'd have to zero-out the memory space the variables you've stored the user/pass data in before the app exits, e.g. `password = 'thisisnottherealpassword';` to overwrite the actual values. If the memory space the data was in happened to get swapped out to disk, then you'll have the values stored on disk until that particular bit of swap space gets overwritten, etc...

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: You're looking for `SecureString`.

Comment: You can use the [`SecureString` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) for that.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I _hope_ that he's just calling `LogonUser`.  There are reasons to do this.

Comment: @MarkB zeroing out isn't that easy thanks to relocation. And overwriting isn't simple either if the swap file is on a SSD thanks to weak leveling.

Comment: @MarcB How do I make sure that non of the password is store anywhere on the disk.

Comment: You can't mix WinForms and ASP.Net.

Comment: @SLaks Sorry I fix it. It's suppose to be WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are afraid that you're keeping this information in memory you may look at [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes the program is web software...

The users's browser might store it, if they tell their browser to store that password. There is nothing you can do about that as the developer of the software.

Unless you specifically have your software write the password to some kind of storage on your server (file, database, memcached, etc), the password will not be stored in your program.

Comment: The program is not a web software but a regular C# program using the window form.

Comment: in your edit to your question you say you're using ASP.NET, not windows forms.

Comment: @Jason Sorry I'm still quite new to C#. Actually I'm using Window Form. I fix it already.